# Is an unencrypted paypal button secure if you make suitable checks in your IPN?

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn, payment

I'm using the following code to create a payment button and am modifying the values for amount,currency_code and custom dynamically:

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="test1@example.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test payment" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.example.com/IPN.aspx" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/Thanks.aspx" />
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test app">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
```

I'm passing the productID of the product im selling in 'custom' and then I'm then doing some checks in my IPN.aspx to check that the values for amount and currency have not been modified by using the ProductID to get details of the product price & currency from my database and comparing this to what is returned by paypal.  Surely this is secure because if the details don't match in my IPN the payment is not recorded?

I've looked around for answers to this and people just say that it's not secure because you can use fiddler/tamperdata etc to change the values of the amount or currency code but surely if I'm checking in the IPN then this is secure.  What are the security risks of doing the payment this way and is there any way to hack or abuse it?

Comment: Regardless of your IPN workflow, [You should always use HTTPS](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/encrypt-in-transit/why-https) for everything.

Comment: yes thanks, my urls are only examples and will eventually use https.  However https posts can be intercepted with fiddler between the browser and server as I recall so i think the parameters could still be modified, no?  It's obviously less secure to use http rather than https but is there a specific attack i should look out for and guard against in this type of scenario and if so can you give me an example of the attack and defense?

Comment: Encryption with HTTPS and secure programming are completely separate but necessary things. HTTPS is not going to save you from XSS, direct object access, SQL Injection, etc., etc. HTTPS simply prevents inspection of and tampering with data across the wire, after the request leaves your "walls" (browser, proxy server). Are you familiar with the OWASP top 10?

Comment: no i'll check it out